# Elementary proof that $\sum_{j=1}^{n} \prod_{k \neq j} \frac{1}{1+(a_j - a_k + i)^2} \in \mathbb{R}$ for $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ distinct

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

By a straightforward contour integral, one can show that for $a_1, \dots, a_n \in \mathbb{R}$ distinct, we have

$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \prod_{j=1}^{n} \frac{1}{1+(x-a_j)^2} \, dx = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \prod_{k \neq j} \frac{1}{1+(a_j - a_k  + i)^2}$$

and therefore the latter sum is real-valued. Is there an elementary (or at least purely algebraic) way to show this, without using complex analysis?

Comment: This should be related to [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial).

Comment: after taking conjugates and some easy algebra, it suffices to show that:
$$\sum\limits_{j=1}^n\prod\limits_{k\neq j}\dfrac{a_j-a_k}{1+(a_j-a_k)^2} = 0,$$
which is probably established with one nice trick with Lagrange Interpolation.

Comment: If $p(x) = (x-a_1)\dots(x-a_n),$ then the above same as showing:
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\dfrac{p'(a_j)}{p(a_j-i)p(a_j+i)} = 0.$$
maybe someone can finish this off.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since nobody seems to be willing to answer, let me expand my comment above.

Consider a more general problem. Suppose we started with
$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{\prod_{k=1}^n(x-z_k)(x-\bar z_k)},$$
where  all $z_k$'s are pairwise distinct and all $\Im z_k>0$. The analog of your problem would then be to show that
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{i}{(z_j-\bar z_j)\prod_{k\ne j}^n(z_j-z_k)(z_j-\bar z_k)}\; \in\mathbb R,$$
which is the same as to show that
$$\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{(z_j-\bar z_j)\prod\limits_{k\ne j}^n(z_j-z_k)(z_j-\bar z_k)}+\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{ 1}{(\bar z_j- z_j)\prod\limits_{k\ne j}^n(\bar z_j-z_k)(\bar z_j-\bar z_k)}=0\tag{1}$$
This is a special case of the identity
$$\qquad\qquad\sum_{j=1}^N\frac{1}{\prod_{k\ne j}^N(u_j-u_k)}=0,\tag{2}$$
which corresponds to setting in (2) $N=2n$ and  $u_j=z_j$, $u_{j+n}=\bar z_j$ for $j=1,\ldots,n$. It thus remains to prove (2).

Knowing the beginning of the story, one proof is straightforward: it suffices to compute  $\displaystyle\int_\Gamma\frac{du}{\prod_{k=1}^N(u-u_j)}$ by residues in two different ways (here $\Gamma$ is a closed contour around $u_1,\ldots,u_N$). Shrinking the contour $\Gamma$ produces the left side of (2), while expanding it to infinity gives zero.

If instead we want an algebraic proof of (2), we may use [Lagrange interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). Given $f_1,\ldots,f_N\in\mathbb C$, there exists a unique polynomial $Q(x)$ of degree $N-1$ such that $Q(u_k)=f_k$, and moreover
$$Q(x)=\sum_{j=1}^Nf_j\prod_{k\ne j}^N\frac{x-u_k}{u_j-u_k}.$$
Choose $f_1=\ldots=f_N=1$ so that $Q(x)=1$. The previous formula then transforms into
$$\sum_{j=1}^N\prod_{k\ne j}^N\frac{x-u_k}{u_j-u_k}=1.$$
Equating the coefficients of $x^{N-1}$ at both sides immediately yields (2).